# How i can show two 3d models without mesh overlapping?

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I have a problem, I'm developing a configuration application in R3F for the fashion sector. The wish is to render two 3d objects like a jacket and a shirt however, the problem I can't solve is mesh overlapping. I would like all the mesh of the shirt to fit under the jacket dynamically without resize or morph. Does anyone have any suggestions? I tried stencil masks and blending but couldn't figure it out. Attached are two images for you to understand

Thank you all[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0vSL.png)

I'm training to use stencil mask and blending